# how to retain and display the checkbox selection in visualforce paging?

Tags: visualforce, pagination

i have a visualforce page where i displays a grid with checkbox selection for each row in it. The issue is when i select the checkboxes in page 1 and navigate to page 2 and comes back to page 1, the checkbox selection disappears(unchecked) in page 1. i need to retain and display the checkbox selections while i moving across the pages back and forth. How can i fix this? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found some articles. I think it may be useful for you.

http://salesforcehelpinghands.blogspot.sg/2012/10/pagination-with-maintaing-state-of.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823107/how-to-find-out-which-checkboxes-have-been-selected-on-the-next-page-in-visualfo/14825189#14825189